# Running at command ran the script immediately

Tags: shell, at

I tried to use "at" command to stop and start the server at the certain time, but for some reason the script ran immediately. I tried different ways to do that, but it would always run. What am I doing wrong?
I tried to do it like this:

```
./stop | at 03:52 092421
```

and like this:

```
./start | at 04:00 tommorow
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are invoking `./stop` (or `./start`). It's not `at` who runs the script immediately. It's you.

By `./stop | at …` you run `./stop` and `at` simultaneously. This is how piping (`|`) works in a shell. The *output* from `./stop` goes to `at`. This is not what you want.

`at` expects a command (that you want to run later) as a string on its standard input. Instead of the output of `./stop` you want to pass a *string* that says `./stop`. A basic way to pipe a string is to `echo` it:

```
echo './stop' | at …
```

This will run `echo` and `at`. The latter tool will take the output of the former tool. The output will literally be `./stop`. This is what you want.